# Place two text fields within a single <div> class

Tags: users, forms

I have assigned class names to both user name & password text fields in user login block separately like this and it's working.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id, $element) {
   if ( TRUE === in_array( $form_id, array( 'user_login', 'user_login_block') ) ) {
       $form['name']['#attributes']['class'] = array('mgnB10', 'fntXL', 'drkFg1');
       $form['pass']['#attributes']['class'] = array('fntXL', 'drkFg1');
   }
}
```

I want to include these fields inside a single '' and assign class name for design purpose, like this.

```
<div class="class-name">
  username field
  password field
</div>
```

I am using the following code but I didn't get the expected output.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id, $element) {
   if ( TRUE === in_array( $form_id, array( 'user_login', 'user_login_block') ) ) {
       $form['user_login']['#attributes']['class'] = array('#prefix' => 'myclass');
       $form['name']['#attributes']['class'] = array('mgnB10', 'fntXL', 'drkFg1');
       $form['pass']['#attributes']['class'] = array('fntXL', 'drkFg1');
       $form['user_login'] = array('#suffix' => '</div>');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you,

In Drupal 7 you can achieve it by using the *#prefix* and *#suffix* properties in `hook_form_alter()`.

```
   /**
    * Implements hook_form_alter().
    */
    function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
      switch ($form_id) {
        case 'user_login':
        case 'user_login_block':
          $form['name']['#prefix'] = '&#60;div class="username-password-wrapper"&#62;';
          $form['pass']['#suffix'] = '&#60;/div&#62;';
          break;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this programmatically, you can use the [Field Group](https://drupal.org/project/field_group) module, which allows you to group fields using the *Manage Fields* tab in the UI.

`<div>` can be selected as the group type.

Comment: I installed Field Group module. In manage field page of Article I added group and two fields inside it. In Widget column I saw <pre>div open
required_fields yes
classes group-test-group field-group-div
show_label Yes
label_element Header 3
effect None
speed Fast</pre> Now it doesn't work and I how can I add <pre> div close</pre>. How do I add close div?